# How to add the input values of eight labels to an array, then get the prime numbers of the array? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm very new in the javascript and I want to put the values of 8 labels (text) to an array of 8 numbers, then get the prime numbers of the array, I can make the array and I can set the 8 labels in the html, but I'm not sure with taking that values to the array. If you could help me it will be awesome, thanks!

The code of my solver button:

```
$('#btn1').click(function () {
    var primes = [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true];

    var limit = Math.sqrt(8);

    for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        if (primes[i] === true) {
            for (var j = i * i; j < 8; j += i) {
                primes[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        if (primes[i] === true) {
            console.log(i + " " + primes[i]);
        }
    }

});
```

The code of the labels:

```
<label>1. </label> <input id="input1" type="text"><br>
<label>2. </label> <input id="input2" type="text"><br>
<label>3. </label> <input id="input3" type="text"><br>
<label>4. </label> <input id="input4" type="text"><br>
<label>5. </label> <input id="input5" type="text"><br>
<label>6. </label> <input id="input6" type="text"><br>
<label>7. </label> <input id="input7" type="text"><br>
<label>8. </label> <input id="input8" type="text"><br>
```

Comment: what is `value`? it doesn't seem to be defined in your code, is that defined outside the scope of your click handler or is it a typo?

Comment: Oh sorry! Value is the "8" from the array size

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are making the array a small finite number (8) and then looping the values? The first `var` and first `for` loop could be simplified to `var primes = [,true,true,true,true,true,true,true];` if you're really certain you always want 8. Otherwise maybe consider replacing 8 with a variable.

Comment: I get it, I'll edit it as you say, thanks, I still don't know how to send the values to the array, with a "push"? but then what? how I can call the array to the solver function? :(

Comment: "...send the values to the array with a 'push'?" you mean like: `primes.push(newValue);`

Comment: Yes! but more like `primes.push($('#input1').text());..`

Comment: Ah I see. OK so perhaps I'm not understanding your question. You need help with: 1.) take values from 8 text inputs into the array, 2.) determine if the value (from the input) is a prime number, 3.) log the prime numbers to the console. Is that right?

Comment: That's exactly what I wish for! actually I'll log the prime numbers to a container, but that's not a problem, Thanks mason81

Comment: @GustavoR. Which numbers do you need to check for primes?  Integers from 1 to 8 (as your program appears to be doing) or numbers that are entered in the text fields?

Comment: @AdeelZafarSoomro Numbers that are entered in the text fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code to check if number is prime (from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24094774/1013526):

```
function isPrime(n) {

   // If n is less than 2 or not an integer then by definition cannot be prime.
   if (n < 2) {return false}
   if (n != Math.round(n)) {return false}

   // Now assume that n is prime, we will try to prove that it is not.
   var isPrime = true;

   // Now check every whole number from 2 to the square root of n. If any of these divides n exactly, n cannot be prime.
   for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
      if (n % i == 0) {isPrime = false}
   }

   // Finally return whether n is prime or not.
   return isPrime;

}
```

Code for the solver button click:

```
$('#btn1').click(function () {
    var count = 8;   // in case you decide to change this later
    var primes = {}; // object instead of array

    for (var i = 1; i < count; i++) {
        var value = $('#input'+i).val(); // get the input value;
        value = parseInt(value); // convert it from string to int.

        primes[i] = {};
        primes[i].value = value;
        primes[i].isPrime = isNan(value) ? false : isPrime(value);

        $('#result'+i).text(primes[i].isPrime ? 'Prime' : 'Not Prime');
    }

    console.dir(primes); // log output to console.
    $('#container2').html(JSON.stringify(primes)); // output to container2 as string

});
```

The code of the labels (modified):

```
<label>1. </label> <input id="input1" type="text"><span id="result1"></span><br>
<label>2. </label> <input id="input2" type="text"><span id="result2"></span><br>
<label>3. </label> <input id="input3" type="text"><span id="result3"></span><br>
<label>4. </label> <input id="input4" type="text"><span id="result4"></span><br>
<label>5. </label> <input id="input5" type="text"><span id="result5"></span><br>
<label>6. </label> <input id="input6" type="text"><span id="result6"></span><br>
<label>7. </label> <input id="input7" type="text"><span id="result7"></span><br>
<label>8. </label> <input id="input8" type="text"><span id="result8"></span><br>
```

If you want to make the output a little more pretty you could do something like this:

```
var output = '<pre>';
for (var i in primes) {
    output += primes[i].value + ': ' + primes[i].isPrime + "\n";
}
output += '</pre>';
$('#container2').html(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! @mason81 I'll implement it to my code, Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome @GustavoR. Happy coding. Let me know if it doesn't work or if you need help understanding something.

Comment: Actually I'm dealing with the `console.dir(primes)` in the usual way to return in javascript I use to do something like this: `$('#container1').html();` instead of the "console.dir" but I'm trying to change it @mason81

Comment: `console.dir(primes)` just prints the contents of primes to the console. If you look at the changes I made to the labels and text boxes you'll see I added some spans and in the JavaScript I put "Prime" or "Not Prime" with that ternary.

Comment: how can I send those prime numbers to another container? I think that would be clearer to see, I normally use the `$('#container1').html` but it doesn't work with that code

Comment: I'll answer my question with the whole HTML for you to view it better @mason81

Comment: @GustavoR. sorry, I made a mistake in my original answer. I fixed it. It wasn't displaying in the spans because I was using the primes object improperly. It should work now. If you want to print to your container, you could use `$('#container2').html(JSON.stringify(primes));` otherwise you'll need to come up with a way to make the output a little more pretty.

Comment: @GustavoR. i updated my answer again with a way to make the output a little easier to read (see the bottom of the answer).

Comment: Thank you again! I'll try to do it when I get to my home, I'm at college right now, but now I can understand the output better!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create an array and iterate over each element in the array. Instead, you can just write a function to check whether the passed label is a prime number or not. If it is prime, fill the HTML. I have written my function in PHP but the logic is same for javascript.

```
function is_prime($number)
{
    if ($number==1)
        return false;
    if ($number==2)
        return true;
    $sqrt = sqrt($number);
    $floor = floor($sqrt);
    for ($i=2 ; $i <= $floor ; $i++)
    {
        if ($number % $i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
$start = 1;
$labels = 8;
for($i = 1; $i <= $labels; $i++)
{
    if(is_prime($i))
    {
        echo '<label>'.$i.'. </label>'.'<input id="input'. $i.'" type="text" value=" '. $i .'">'.'<br>';
    }
}

// output

2. 2
3. 3
5. 5
7. 7
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you, I get it, I will try with this logic! :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's my entire HTML:

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#btn1').click(function () {
                var count = 8;   // in case you decide to change this later
                var primes = {}; // object instead of array

                for (var i = 1; i < count; i++) {
                    var value = $('#input'+i).val(); // get the input value;
                    value = parseInt(value); // convert it from string to int.

                    primes.i.value = value;
                    primes.i.isPrime = isNan(value) ? false : isPrime(value);
                    $('#result'+i).text(primes.i.isPrime ? 'Prime' : 'Not Prime');
                    }
            $('#container2').html(primes); // log output to console.
            });

            function isPrime(n) {

            // If n is less than 2 or not an integer then by definition cannot be prime.
            if (n < 2) {return false}
            if (n != Math.round(n)) {return false}
            // Now assume that n is prime, we will try to prove that it is not.
            var isPrime = true;
            // Now check every whole number from 2 to the square root of n. If any of these divides n exactly, n cannot be prime.
            for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
                if (n % i == 0) {isPrime = false}
            }
            // Finally return whether n is prime or not.
            return isPrime;
            }

        });
</script>      
</head>

<body>
    <center><h2>Prime Numbers Calculator.</h2><br></center>
    <div class="well">
        <div class="container" id="container1">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>1. </label> <input id="input1" type="text"><span id="result1"></span><br>
                <label>2. </label> <input id="input2" type="text"><span id="result2"></span><br>
                <label>3. </label> <input id="input3" type="text"><span id="result3"></span><br>
                <label>4. </label> <input id="input4" type="text"><span id="result4"></span><br>
                <label>5. </label> <input id="input5" type="text"><span id="result5"></span><br>
                <label>6. </label> <input id="input6" type="text"><span id="result6"></span><br>
                <label>7. </label> <input id="input7" type="text"><span id="result7"></span><br>
                <label>8. </label> <input id="input8" type="text"><span id="result8"></span><br>
            </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="container" id="container2">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="container" id="container3">

            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <center><button id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary"> Calculate</button>
        <button id="btn2" class="btn btn-primary"> Show</button>
        <button id="btn3" class="btn btn-primary"> Sort</button>
        <button id="btn4" class="btn btn-primary"> Clean</button></center>
</body>
```

But still have an issue showing the result in the other container