# Prime Number Function in Javascript ...multiple statements

Tags: javascript

So I'm tasked with making program that can tell whether a number is prime or not. I want to solve this problem using a multiple if-statement. The one that I came up with is awkward. So i just want some feedback on how to make it better.:

```
function primenumber(num) {
    if (num / num === 1 && num % 2 !== = 0 || num % 3 !== = 0 | num % 5 !== = 0 | num % 7 !== = 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

I figured these numbers are the lowest common denominators. So a number is prime if these numbers don't divide evenly into it.  Any feedback is greatly appreciated. Keep in mind that I am new to Javascript.

Comment: First off, that isn't the definition of a prime number. 2, 3, 5, and 7 are all prime and this would return false for those

Comment: _A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself._ - [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number)

Comment: Have you done any research into [testing of prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test)?

Comment: Check this answer... [isPrime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094731/how-to-check-if-the-value-in-a-text-box-is-prime-or-not-with-jquery)

Comment: Don't quite know where to start. Maybe run this against `jshint`? or, view the console for errors? or, read some beginning JS tutorials? or, don't give up your day job?

Comment: Hi Everyone, 
I figured it out:

    If((num === 1) || (num === 2) || (num === 3) || (num === 5) || (num     === 7))
    { return true;
    }

    If((num%2===0) || (num%3===0) || (num%5===0) || (num%7===0)){
    return false;}
    }
    return true; 
    }

It may not be the most sophisticated coding but it's mine and it works at least according to coderbyte. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
If((num === 1) || (num === 2) || (num === 3) || (num === 5) || (num     === 7))
{ return true;
}

If((num%2===0) || (num%3===0) || (num%5===0) || (num%7===0)){
return false;}
}
return true; 
}
```

It may not be the most sophisticated coding but it's mine and it works perfectly.. at least according to coderbyte

Comment: Sorry if you took it that way. By the way, your code fails for 11.

Comment: No worries... It was late and i was being defensive so I'm sorry....anyway I tested 11 and it came back "true" on coderbyte.......did you test my code?

Comment: Yes, I did. For instance, it fails on 121, which is 11x11.

Comment: I appreciate you checking...you're right about 121...it returned as a prime when it fact it isn't. My code fails by failing to consider the squares of prime numbers greater than 7.  I will look at it again. Thanks